# How can i customize greenlight from big blue button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigbluebutton

For my one project I use [greenlight](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/greenlight)

first, I installed greenlight on the server but I want to customize the landing page but I don't how to do it. so I installed rails application in my server, I did some changes like adding a custom class. but no effect on the landing page.

can someone explain me how can I fully customize greenlight directly on the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its for Greenlight V1.**

After searching bit i found below steps to setup ruby on rails greenlight app on server.

**If you already setup greenlight with docker then please stop docker.
for docker compose you need to run command `docker-compose down`. it will stop docker image and you will see 404 on your server .**

You need to fork greenlight from github first then clone that project in server you can clone it anywhere on server just make sure your server is running on port 5000.

you can checkout more from [here](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/greenlight-v2.html#running-greenlight-as-a-rails-application)

This are all the commands I used to have greenlight running without docker which works for me

```
======================
apt-get install curl

sudo apt-get install gnupg2

curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | sudo gpg2 --import -

sudo gpg2 --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable

source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

rvm requirements

rvm list known

rvm install 2.5.1

rvm use 2.5.1 --default 

ruby --version

gem install rails

cd /

git clone https://github.com/bigbluebutton/greenlight.git

cd /greenlight

nano Gemfile

(mover dotenv-rails fuera del bloque test/development)

gem install bundler -v 1.16.1

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

bundle

cp greenlight.nginx /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/greenlight.nginx

systemctl restart nginx

rake secret
(Copy the secret generated, you will need it for .env)

bbb-conf --secret
(Copy the URL and Secret, you will need it for .env)

cp sample.env .env

nano .env
(fill the Secret and BigBlueButton credentials you generated before)

RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate

rails assets:precompile

rails s -p 5000 -e production

=======================================
```

In this project do changes as you require and run server again.

Comment: Hello, please how to edit greenlight front-end after the commands ?

Comment: @AnassElFakir if you know ror it's very easy to customize it. for customizing landing page please refer this doc https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/greenlight/gl-customize.html#customizing-the-landing-page . You just have to go those files and edit it.

Comment: Thank you, yes when i edit index.html.erb i must restart docker-compose to apply changes, but using your steps i get 404 not found page.

Comment: @AnassElFakir was it working earlier?  Did you check docker image is correct or not? Check rails server is running? if you are following above steps, try to kill pid of rails and run rails server again in background prodcution mode.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must have installed greenlight installed on server
for changing the color of theme :

```
vim config/application.rb
```

scroll down and  you will found following code just replace code of color with your desire:

```
# Default primary color if the user does not specify one 
config.primary_color_default = "#116ceb" 


# Default primary color lighten if the user does not specify one
config.primary_color_lighten_default = "#e8eff9"


# Default primary color darken if the user does not specify one.
config.primary_color_darken_default = "#316cbe"
```

there is lots of things you can customize..(almost everything).

And one of the most important thing after making changes to any file you must have to rebuild your image of docker you can do that by running the command which is given at the end.
This command is for default settings if you have changed the name of your image please replace `bigbluebutton/greenlight release-v2` with yourimage name.
you will find your image name here:

```
#this will open the yml file for docker settings
vim docker-compose.yml

#file will look like this:

ersion: '3'

services:
  app:
    entrypoint: [bin/start]
    image: bigbluebutton/greenlight:release-v2  #nmae of your image 
    container_name: greenlight-v2
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5000:80
```

copy this command and past into the terminal blow command for rebuilding your docker image

```
docker-compose down && ./scripts/image_build.sh bigbluebutton/greenlight release-v2 && docker-compose up -d
```